# How to prove if $ A \subset B $ then $ A \cup C \subset B \cup C $

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I don't really know how to approach this question:

> Let $ U $ be a universe. Use an element argument to prove the following
>   statement.
>
> For all sets $ A, B $ and $ C $ in $ P(U) $, if $ A \subset B $ then $ A \cup C \subset B \cup C $

My working:

Logical form: $ ( A \subset B ) \Rightarrow ( A \cup C \subset B \cup C) $

Let $ x \in ( A \subset B ) $

---

I don' really know how to do from here. Can anyone here help me understand? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well let $x \in A \cup C$, then what happens if $x \in A$? Or if $x \in C$?

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes a figure is worth 1000 words:

[image]

Comment: Oooppss.... I'll fix the figure and repost.  (Thanks.) . But the concept should nevertheless be clear.

Comment: Now that the figure is corrected, I've deleted my previous comment to avoid any future confusion.

Comment: Thank you, @David G. Stork. This helps me in visualising and understand better.

Answer (score 1):

Take an arbitrary element $x \in A \cup C$. Then $x \in A \vee x \in C$. If $x \in A$, then $x \in B$, so $x \in B \cup C$ by the properties of unions. If $x \in C$, it still follows that $x \in B \cup C$. By proving for an arbitrary element $x \in A \cup C$ that $x \in B \cup C$, we prove that $A \cup C \subseteq B \cup C$.

However, it is *not* necessarily true that $A \cup C \subset B \cup C$ (note the proper subset vs. subset). Suppose that $U = \mathbb{N}$, $A = \{1,2\}$, $B = \{1,2,3\}$, and $C = \{3,4,5\}$. Then clearly, $A \cup C \not \subset B \cup C$.

Note: I see you used $P(U)$, not $U$, but a similar intuition can be applied to create a counterexample for power sets.

Comment: Thanks alot, I understand better. Just to confirm on why `A∪C⊄B∪C`. Is it because `A∪C = {1,2,3,4,5}` and `B∪C = {1,2,3,4,5}` Where both `A∪C` and `B∪C` have exactly the same element. However, `A subset B`, means A needs to have lesser element than B.  Thus `A∪C⊄B∪C` ?

Comment: @J.S Effectively, yes. For $A$ to be a proper subset of $B$, there must be some element in $B$ that is _not_ in $A$.